# Area of paralellogram

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, determinant, area, cross-product

Find the area of parallelogram of the two vectors (6,0,1,3) and (2,1,3,1). The area is magnitude of the cross product of the two vectors. Right now the only way i was taught to do the cross product is getting the determinant of putting the vectors in and i,j,k matrix. I dont know how to do it with 4 points of the vector.

Comment: The cross-product formula for area is only applicable in 3D space; indeed, there is no such thing as a cross product in 4D space. So you'll need something more basically geometric than that. Try to figure out how you'd compute the area of a parallelogram in 2D space, for instance, without using cross product.

Comment: base x height ?

Comment: The area would be $\|a\|\|b\||\sin\theta|$.

Comment: The answer sqrt(46x15-18x18) how does this make sense

Comment: Since $\sin^2\theta=1-\cos^2\theta$ you can do $\|a\|^2\|b\|^2-|a\cdot b|^2$ to get the square of the area.

Comment: Thank you much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For:
$$
\vec v=(6,0,1,3)^T \qquad \vec u=(2,1,3,1)^T
$$
we have:
$$\vec v \cdot \vec u= 18 \qquad |\vec v|=\sqrt{46} \qquad |\vec u|=\sqrt{15}
$$

so, the angle $\theta$ between the two vectors is such that:
$$
\cos \theta= \frac{18}{\sqrt{46}\sqrt{15}} \qquad \sin \theta= \sqrt{1-\cos^2 \theta}
$$

And the area is:
$$
A= |\vec v| \cdot |\vec u| \sin \theta= \sqrt{46}\sqrt{15}\sqrt{1-\frac{18^2}{46 \cdot 15}} =\sqrt{46\cdot 15 - 18^2}
$$

Comment: this is the answer that *arctic term* has already provided !

Comment: @GCab You're right, however answering questions through comments is discouraged in general.

Answer (score 3):

The area of your (v,w)-parallelogram is equal to $\sqrt{Gram(v,w)}=\sqrt{\det(AA^T)}$, with the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}v & w\end{bmatrix}$.
See, for example,  [Why is the volume of a parallelepiped equal to the square root of $\sqrt{det(AA^T)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/981238/why-is-the-volume-of-a-parallelepiped-equal-to-the-square-root-of-sqrtdetaa/982191#982191) or [How do I compute the area of this parallelogram](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1869441/how-do-i-compute-the-area-of-this-parallelogram).